# How to fix Windows batch file FOR command returing "Active code page: 65001"

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

If I understand correctly this batch script

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`time /t`) do (
  echo "%%i"
)
echo "done"
```

should just print the time and then "done"

Instead though on my machine, Windows 10 Pro x64 it prints

```
>test.bat
>for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`time /t`) do (echo "%i" )
>(echo "Active code page: 65001" )
"Active code page: 65001"
>(echo "17:48" )
"17:48"
>echo "done"
"done"
```

Why is it doing this and how do I fix it so it just gets the time and not this "Active code page: 65001" result. This is breaking build scripts as it doesn't matter what command goes in the FOR command the first line is always "Active code page: 65001"

To be clear I'm looking for an OS setting fix, not a fix to the batch file. The real batch files I'm trying to run are from build scripts in open source projects and they are failing because of this issue.

Comment: this looks strange. What if you set `chcp 437` at the begining of your script?

Comment: same results: https://pastebin.com/37QsMyGD :(

Comment: Check if the registry keys `\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`  under `HKLM` or `HKCU` are configured to run anything when the `cmd` instances are created.

Comment: Also try to check your date format settings in the control panel or the registry. the output you are giving is usually produced by `CHCP` command.

Comment: that was it! under HKLM ... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: same result can be achieved with `echo %time:~0,5%` (if `time /t` isn't just a placeholder for some other command)

Comment: @MCND, please post your comment as the answer so we can get this thread off of the unanswered list.

Comment: @jwdonahue, done, but I'm not sure this has not been answered before.

Comment: If you find a dupe please mark as dupe. I have no idea how that got in my registry but @MCND thank's so much you saved my life :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we run a command and we get the correct output, but it is preceded by the output of another command, somehow this unexpected command is run before our intended command.

The usual suspect is a batch file created with the same name that the command we are calling, but in this case, being `time` an internal command, this can not be the case, internal commands have precedence over external commands (default behaviour).

If `time` is an internal command, how can another command being called?

When `for /f` needs to process the output of a command a separate `cmd` instance is created to execute that command. The output generated in this separate instance is processed by the code in the `do` clause of the `for /f` command.

The creation of this separate instance can be the source of the unexpected output.

Reading the help information shown by `cmd /?` we can see that there are two registry keys

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

that can be configured to run commands every time a new `cmd` instance is created (unless the `/D` switch is used when starting the `cmd` instance).

This is the most probable place where to find why you get the `Active code page: 65001` output.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the registry you can control the code page simply by creating a file %HOMEPATH%\init.cmd.
Mine says:

```
@ECHO OFF
CHCP 65001 > nul
```

You need to suppress the output from CHCP to avoid the undesired output.