# Jshell crashes when i press BackSpace button in windows cmd

Tags: java, windows, backspace, jshell

when I open windows `cmd` and type `jshell` , it works, but when I'm writing something . whenever I press the `BackSpace` key . for example if I want to delete a letter that is wrong . jshell crashes with bellow error , i'm using `windows 10` , and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1` is my only path in windows `System Environment variables` , i also use `cmd` as terminal .
here is the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: charsetName
        at java.base/java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:464)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:537)
        at jdk.internal.le/jdk.internal.jline.extra.AnsiInterpretingOutputStream.write(AnsiInterpretingOutputStream.java:92)
        at java.base/java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:157)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:233)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:312)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:316)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:153)
        at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:254)
        at jdk.internal.le/jdk.internal.jline.console.ConsoleReader.flush(ConsoleReader.java:1052)
        at jdk.internal.le/jdk.internal.jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:3259)
        at jdk.internal.le/jdk.internal.jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2383)
        at jdk.internal.le/jdk.internal.jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2371)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.ConsoleIOContext.readLine(ConsoleIOContext.java:142)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellTool.getInput(JShellTool.java:1261)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellTool.run(JShellTool.java:1174)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellTool.start(JShellTool.java:975)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellToolBuilder.start(JShellToolBuilder.java:254)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellToolProvider.main(JShellToolProvider.java:120)
```

Comment: Worth mentioning the details such as `OS` you are working on, `shell` you're running from and `jshell` version as well. Could possibly be a bug with JDK.

Comment: In my case, only happening with PowerShell.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53900918/jshell-error-java-lang-nullpointerexception-charsetname) looks like a good duplicate, have you checked it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with the active code page. Specifically `65001` is a problem and popular one to have so my best guess is that this is the one being used but see the link later for some choices.

On windows:

```
> java --version
java 11.0.1 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Check the active code page with `chcp`. If it is set to `65001` (maybe you've been playing around with this hack to get utf-8 characters to display in your terminal) the issue is reliably reproducible.

```
> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001
> jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11.0.1
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell>TypeAnything<backspace>Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: charsetName
        at java.base/java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:464)
        at ...
```

### The solution

Take your pick from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html, but `chcp 850` should do the trick.

```
> chcp 850 && jshell
Active code page: 850
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11.0.1
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> TypeAnything<backspace>
```

#### PowerShell specific

The idea is the same (change the console encoding) but the commands are slightly different. Again the idea is to change the encoding. Look at the current code page with `[Console]::OutputEncoding.CodePage`, we want to switch that to one from the list like `850`.

```
> [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(850)
> jshell
```

Comment: I was pretty sure that was encoding issues but... Still not working in my case for PowerShell :( And there is plenty places of "enconding" for pwsh. Anyway I will pay the bounty.

Comment: @lucasvc I've updated with a power shell command, does that help with your case?

Comment: \@SpencerPark Nice! It works! But then means that JShell only works with `Latin-1` enconding and not `UTF-8`? What an encoding-nightmare...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue using [zulu openjdk-11](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk) and Jshell worked fine.